# Install old version of plugin from admin panel?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

Is there a way to install an old version of a plugin that is hosted on the WordPress.org plugin repository from the admin panel?

I know that you can easily go to the [WordPress.org plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/), grab any version of any plugin you want, FTP the files onto your website, and then activate from the Plugins admin page.  However, I was wondering if there is a way to install a plugin using the Plugins -> Add New page and choose a version other than the latest.  I am helping someone out with testing, and I have Administrator access to their admin panel, but not FTP access.

Comment: I think you can download the older plugin version in zip format and upload it from admin panel from Install Plugins -> Upload option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can download the older plugin version in zip format and upload it from admin panel from Install Plugins -> Upload option.